# how to redirect domain to dynamic subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have store in mysite.com and in this site, there is some store like apple and... .
users can view this stores with virtual subdomains like http://apple.mysite.com

Therefore, I create .htaccess in root file manager:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /stores.php?id_store=%1 [P,L]
```

then in "Subdomains" in Cpanel I create ***.mysite.com** and in "Document Root" set **/public_html**

Now, how can I park or redirect domain to this dynamic subdomain with htaccess code?
For example:
park or redirect **applestore123.com** to **apple.mysite.com**

I have Shared Host Server.

Comment: please help me!how to solve this problem? :s

Answer (score 0):

For applestore123.com to apple.mywebsite you have to change your htaccess rule like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^applestore123.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) apple.mysite.com$ [QSA,R=301,L]
```